# Having focused and worked

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I am writing a letter of motivation for a master program and it begins as follow:

> After having focused and worked in the field of optics and photonics throughout my physics bachelor studies, I am convinced that joining the Master of Science in X at the X-University will deepen my knowledge and broaden my perspectives in these fields.

I am not sure if "After having focused and worked" is correct in this paragraph.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but wonder about "joining the Master of Science in X"  Is join the right verb, and do you need the word programme after X--e.g., "I am convinced the undertaking the Master of Science in X programme at ......(or program--but it sounds like this is outside the US)

Comment: @Xanne As I'm not a native english speaker, I'm not totally sure about the usage of "joining". For me it sounds a little weird to say "Master of Science in X programme", maybe it is because in my language it doesn't make sense. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Here I posted a question about the usage of "joining": [http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379819/joining-a-graduate-program]

Comment: You were right! I used "enrolling in" and add the word "program" @Xanne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right to doubt the use of 'focused and worked' as in your opening line, because the phrasing is awkward and a little weak. This is because:

1. *'Focused'* should be followed by *'on'*, not *'in'*.
2. The use of both words is redundant. This is especially so because *'worked'* here does not refer to work experience, which is a critical point of difference when applying to any Masters programme.

As this is the opening line of your letter of motivation, I would suggest going in strong and using only one of these words. I'd recommend something along the lines of *"After having focused specifically on the field of..."* or even, *"After having specialised in the field of..."*.

All the best for your application!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will drop the word "worked" and use "focused specifically on".

Comment: @CristinaAmayaMéndez You're welcome!