# Joining a Graduate Program

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I am using the next phrase in a letter of motivation for applying to a master program:

> I am convinced that **joining** the Master of Science in X at the X-University will deepen my knowledge and broaden my perspectives in ...

I am not sure if "joining" is the correct word to use in this context, or if I should replace it by "enrolling in", "pursuing" or "undertaking".

I would really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Use *enrolling in* and add *program* after Science.

Comment: *Enrolling* (in anything) doesn't deepen your knowledge or broaden your perspectives, but *undertaking* that course of studies might.

Comment: Of course, thank you. I think undertaking is the best option!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a request for writing advice—in this case, a request for help in choosing a more appropriate word to replace "joining" in a particular sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **admission** is a better choice. *Admission* is a more specific word than *joining* in academic contexts.

For more information, refer to:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_and_college_admission

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/admission

Comment: Yes, after **admission to the school** you will **join the Masters program.** Add the word 'program' to your letter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used "enrolling in" and add the word program.